# How to not append the old Result.xml file in Jmeter?

Tags: xml, linux, jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins

In Jmeter in linux, I am creating Result.xml for each test suite on re-running it gets appended to the old Result.xml but i want to create a new Result.xml

For this i need to run  `rm -rf Result.xml`  before  the test plan execution.

I used OS Process Sampler for this in Jmeter as follows :

[3 OS Process Samplers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykf9E.png)

First I need to go to the folder where Result.xml  and Jmeter.jmx files are there. But this path is not fixed.

So I have used  `pushd .`  to save the current path from which Jmeter.jmx file will be run in non-gui mode(same directory where Result.xml will be present).

Then `popd`   to go to this path which should be the folder where  Jmeter.jmx and  Result.xml file is there.

And then remove  `rm -rf Result.xml`  which should remove Result.xml file.

Then execute the rest of the calls and make a new Result.xml file in the same directory.

[Execution sequence of the entire suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10HRr.png)

---

This method is not working properly as, the result of the test execution doesnt give any error but there is no new  Result.xml created. Which means  that even if  OS Process Sampler  are placed before the test suite, it deletes new Result.xml  file. Hence, before Results Tree is created or executed,  Result.xml is made.

How can i run  OS Process Sampler  to remove the old Result.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you cannot remove the file which is being opened by JMeter for writing the results. However you can clean the contents of the file using a single OS Process Sampler configured like:

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler configuration]

---

In general your approach is not very good as using XML output format and having listeners enabled during the test run violates [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as [listeners cause massive IO overhead](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) so I would recommend reconsidering your results saving approach and using [-l command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to specify results file location instead of using the listeners.

Comment: Thank you! It worked !  The   '> Result.xml'   is used to  clear?  what does '>'  do in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define [Working directory](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) in OS sample. You need to write in it the path of the file Result.xml. if not it will execute in bin folder

> Working directory
>   Directory from which command will be executed, defaults > to folder referenced by "user.dir" System property

Comment: My working directory is  dynamic, it can have any root path as in username@hostname  and any path afterwards, So the path is where i am going to run .jmx file .  That's the reason i did " pushd . " to store the path and popd to go to the stored path